# this is impossible to inculde fs library

Tags: javascript, json, require, fs

here i want to use fs library at the js file to create and edit a json file. but whenever i include this namespace an strange error comes up.
if i use

```
var fs = require("fs")
```

it throws the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

if i use (in terms of any order)

```
import fs from "fs"
```

then it throws

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

i even have tried using the require.js file but in that case it throws those errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

now if i use `require(["fs"])` it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

and a few seconds later

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: fs
```

i even have tried to create another js file in the separate folder and use the require in that too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `require()` is node.js stuff, also its `fs` module. You are trying to do this in a browser. It won't work.

Comment: no i am running in the back-end. how do you guys pay difference between front-end and back-end? in my view back-end is somewhere that you are doing stuffs like php, server, database and etc, and in the front-end you are using css, html,js and almost whatever seems colory and beautiful. am i getting something wrong?

Comment: Back-end is anything what happens on the server, front-end is anything what the browser processes. If you see the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in the JS console of a browser, which you probably do, the code containing the `require()` call somehow reached the browser, even if you planned something else to happen.